# Change background of div in HTML using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying yo change the background of a DIV, and I think that my code is correct, but it seems no.
I think the error is on the URL parameter because without parameter the function works.

This is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function imagen(col){
        document.write(col);
        var elem = document.getElementById("fondo");
        elem.style.backgroundImage = url('col');

        }
    </script>

<div class="grid-block" id="fondo" width: 100%; height: 100vh;">
        <div class="heading">
        <a href="pagina1.html" onMouseOver="imagen(uploads/banner-01.jpg)" >Rojo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read up on how `document.write` works and what it does

Comment: The argument to `imagen()` needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write()`? If you want to see the argument for debugging, use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `imagen()` needs to be in quotes. Otherwise it will be evaluated as an expression, and you'll get a syntax error.

You need to use string concatenation to combine the argument with `url()`.

Don't use `document.write()` in functions that run after the DOM is loaded. It will clear the DOM -- see [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) Use `console.log()` for debugging output.

```js
function imagen(col) {
  console.log(col);
  var elem = document.getElementById("fondo");
  elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + col + ')'
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-block" id="fondo" width: 100%; height: 100vh; ">
    <div class="heading ">
    <a href="pagina1.html " onMouseOver="imagen('uploads/banner-01.jpg') " >Rojo</a>
    </div>
</div>
```